# Indices don't update when deleting item from list

Tags: swiftui

I would like to create a view which I can pass an array into and have the view edit the array.  The following code is a simplified example:

```
struct Item: Identifiable {
  var name: String
  var id = UUID()
}

struct EditItems: View {
  @Binding var item_list: [Item]
  
  var body: some View {
    List {
      ForEach(item_list.indices) { idx in
        Text(item_list[idx].name)
      }
      .onDelete(perform: deleteItem)
    }
    .toolbar {
      ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
        EditButton()
      }
    }
  }
  
  func deleteItem(at offsets: IndexSet) {
    item_list.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
  }
}
```

This compiles and runs initially.  I can hit "Edit" and delete a list item.  After deleting the list item, when I hit "Done", I get "Fatal error: Index out of range".  The debugger tells me that my list has 7 items but the line `Text(item_list[idx].name)` is trying to execute with `idx = 7`.

So it appears that after deleting the item the `ForEach` is still running over the old indices instead of the new one shorter indices.  Is this because `item_list` is not `@State`?  When I tried making it both `@State` and `@Binding` I got a bunch of errors.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initializer for `ForEach` that takes in a range can only be used for constant data.

From [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/foreach/init(_:content:)-6db7u):

> The instance only reads the initial value of the provided data and
> doesn’t need to identify views across updates.

Use one of the other `ForEach` initializers, such as:

```
ForEach(item_list.enumerated(), id: \.self) { idx, element in
```

Comment: Well I'll be, I had never notices that some of these are constant and some aren't.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You used constructor of `ForEach` which creates **constant** container, use different one, with explicit identifiers, like

```
List {
  ForEach(item_list.indices, id: \.self) { idx in    // << here !!
    Text(item_list[idx].name)
  }
```